# Build only when get trigger submitted pull request in groovy stage

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I am using jenkins pipeline for build and deploy my application to aws.

I have a problem with:

I would like to build-only that means "build" stage run only and by-pass "deploy" stage in jenkinsfile when we get a trigger "submitted pull request" from bitbucket.

So I think :

```
if (stat.pullrequest != "open")
 stage ("deploy")
```

Please help me to write some condition in groovy.

Answer (score 1):

You can add [when](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) in stage block, like

```
when {
    expression { stat.pullrequest != "open" }
}
```

Comment: got it ```groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: stat for class: groovy.lang.Binding```

Comment: maybe ```pullrequest.stat```'